# Dotted line appears under shape in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

```
    Set shp = aslide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=24, Top:=50, Width:=672, Height:=26.6)
    shp.Name = "First Shape"
    shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 102, 204)
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Title "
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
    shp.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 18
    shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
```

Where aslide is the Activeslide. The issue I got is that a dotted line appears under the text box even when I have clearly made the line visibility to False. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the text have a dotted underline set on it? I am assuming that you are not refering to the dot line that appears when the shape is selected.

Comment: Add a screenshot of what you're seeing or post a copy of the presentation where people can download it and have a look.